# Detecting HTTP Request Errors in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to detect request errors in my angular app in the form of a text message. Kinds of errors that I want to detect are the ones that come up in the chrome console such as network disconnected, ssl verification errors, timeout errors, unable to resolve hostname errors etc.

I am using $http and have tried using interceptors like

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q){
    return{
        requestError : function(req){
            //this is not hit
        }
    }
}
```

Although I am unable to find exactly which conditions should cause the requestError interceptor to fire, I'm assuming the kinds of errors that I am trying to catch are not them.

Does anybody know how I can catch client side http errors in angular?

Comment: This must be control at the server side

Comment: But if there is no internet connection it can't get to the server.

Comment: You can not use the catch segment of the promise? **$http.get("url").then(someFunction).catch(functionToCatchError);**, in the catch section you can console.log the error if you want or raise an event.

Comment: Have you checked that `requestError` is not getting called in your case? I tried stopping my local server and executing an AJAX call from my angularjs app. My `requestError` method is getting called.